# Is there a generating function for $\sqrt{n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I tried to come up with a closed form for the ordinary generating function for the sequence $\{\sqrt{n}\}_0^{\infty}$ but I could not. Is there a way to derive it using the recurrence relation $$a_{n+1} = \sqrt{a_n^2+1}. $$
Because if there is, it is no obvious to me how to do so.

I noticed that the task is trivial if we use a Dirichelt series generating function, namely $\zeta(s-\frac{1}{2})$ but this seems less in interesting to me than having a closed form for the ogf or perhaps even the exponential generating function.

Comment: It's going to very hard if not impossible to find.

Comment: Your (homework) is to find a closed-form for $\sum\sqrt{n}z^n$? (This is the [polylogarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html) ${\rm Li}_{-1/2}(z)$.)

Comment: It is more of a something to think about, but thank you for the input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does exist, defined as $g(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} \sqrt{n} z^n$. It is even a nice function, in that it is analytic in a region around the origin (apply your favorite test). It doesn't have a representation in terms of elementary functions, however.

Comment: Why it doesn't have a representation in terms of elementary functions?

Comment: @lechuza, few functions can be written in terms of elementary functions. I can't find it here on the tablet, but there was a question recently on integrals that can't be written in terms of elementary functions

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the integral formulas for fractional integrals and fractional derivatives (i.e., like half-weight derivatives of the power function; see for example [semi-derivatives](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Semiderivative.html)) in the theory of fractional calculus to express a generating function for this sequence. Note that the resulting generating function will not, however, be "''nice''" in the sense of it being [P-recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#P-recursive_sequences_and_holonomic_generating_functions).